# Android Studio doesn't start, caused by Check Point antivirus moving kotlin-stdlib.jar to quarantine

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, jetbrains-ide

Check Point is seeing this file as a virus for me and is deleting it. I have spent much more time on this issue, but no way.

I have uninstalled the IDE, cache and config folders; reinstalled it again but still didn't work. Is there anyone who has solved such an issue before?

**This is the some details from Check Point dashboard:**

[image]

Comment: Add an exception in you AV software?

Answer (score 2):

The alert is a false positive, see [KT-45368](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-45368) for the details.

All other AV engines have already fixed the alert according to [this report](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/20e91bdfb709c86d722049348f8cc96cb85657d580fc7c11c33c0387ae4b63ac/detection).